# reading from sensors based on softlinks

Tags: linux-device-driver, sensors, linux-mint, iio

How do I read from these sensors? I just found their location, but the folder appears to contain softlinks to another location. My goal is to monitor the gyroscope.

```
$ ls /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 31 23:18 /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:0483:91D1.0018/HID-SENSOR-200073.1.auto/iio:device0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 31 23:18 /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:0483:91D1.0018/HID-SENSOR-200076.2.auto/iio:device1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 31 23:18 /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:0483:91D1.0018/HID-SENSOR-200083.3.auto/iio:device2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 31 23:18 /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device3 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:0483:91D1.0018/HID-SENSOR-200086.4.auto/iio:device3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 31 23:18 /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device4 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:0483:91D1.0018/HID-SENSOR-20008a.5.auto/iio:device4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 31 23:18 /sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device5 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:0483:91D1.0018/HID-SENSOR-200041.6.auto/iio:device5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cat:

```
$ cat /sys/bus/iio/devices/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:0483:91D1.0018/HID-SENSOR-200073.1.auto/iio:device0
```

[Here is](https://archive.fosdem.org/2012/schedule/event/693/127_iio-a-new-subsystem.pdf) a nice presentation on IIO subsystem.